# Play console: Impossible to accept Android Auto addendum

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-auto

Android for Cars addendum to the Developer Distribution Agreement is impossible to accept due to disabled button. Whenever I scroll, select different language , visit those link in agreement or I dont know what else should I do to accept that button.

[image: Android Auto addendum]

When I upload .apk or app bundle it tells me to accept this agreement.

[image: Cannot upload .apk to internal testing due to not accepted agreement]

I am tired of this. I dont know what to do.

Comment: How did you get to that section - I can't even find that

Comment: should be under publication -> settings -> advanced settings -> release types

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs if you aren't the Account Owner Or admin
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844686?hl=en

Comment: I am the account owner but I still can't accept anything

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same convoluted problem. It's easily fixed by going to Setup -> Advanced Settings -> Release Types.

From there add an "Android Auto" release type and click on the "Accept the Android for Cars Terms of Service" link.

Comment: This was soooo annoying, thx so much